# Got ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'google.appengine' even after install google app engine SDK

Tags: python, google-app-engine, jupyter-notebook, google-app-engine-python

I installed the latest Google-App engine and everything is set up. I still cannot use app engine library. Google docs are not helpful on this part.

Here is the command I used in `jupyter` notebook. Python version is `3.6`.

Command used and the trace-back error (**[print-screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gi4ww.png)**):

`from google.appengine.api import images`

> ModuleNotFoundError Traceback (most recent call last)
>    in () ----> 1 from
>   google.appengine.api import images ModuleNotFoundError: No module
>   named 'google.appengine'

Can anyone help me to fix this issue?
Thank you!

Comment: from google.appengine.api import images

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-72-8edb36efae24> in <module>()
----> 1 from google.appengine.api import images

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'google.appengine'

Comment: Did you add the GAE SDK to your path? Something like: `export PATH="/Users/alex/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/:$PATH"`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I just tried to add it to my path. But I still get the same error.